# What does "Missing Operating System" on boot mean?

Tags: installation, boot

So I've got my new computer now, one without any operating system. I have my ubuntu all ready on a USB, it's plugged into the computer. I turn on the computer, it shows a splash screen, then it goes to the black with white text mode (maybe called terminal?) and says "Missing operating system".

What do I do?

Comment: Have you configured the boot order in your BIOS to boot from USB first? Your system's probably expecting to find your OS on your hard drive or optical drive instead unless you manually set this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting this error it means you haven't booted off the USB stick, or the USB stick isn't bootable so when you try to boot off of it, it fails.

Double check that you've created the USB stick correctly, and then ensure when you boot the PC that you select to boot off of the USB stick.

This setting differs between PCs, but usually hitting F2, F12 or Delete on boot let's you either set the setting in the BIOS or select it right from boot.

Comment: I am fairly sure the USB is done correctly. I deleted everything off of it, then used the program they had on the Ubuntu website and the OS downloaded from the website to format the USB. But I don't know how to get the computer to boot from a USB.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out!

Comment: Then you probably need to just figure out how to get your PC to boot off of it. See if it tells you on boot if you can hit a key to go into the BIOS.